# How to add header in csv file using C#

Tags: c#

Basically, I receive excel file from a user that I successfully parsed it. This step is done, now I just need to add the Header. For example Header1, Header2, Header3, Header4, Header5. I have five columns in a csv file. Can someone help please?

```
using System;   
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading.Tasks;   
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;    
using System.Diagnostics;   
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;


namespace Debug01   
{       
   class Program        
   {

private static string errorFile =
@"C:\SourceCode\EMPLOYEE\TEST\OUTPUT\EMPlog.txt";          

static void Main(string[] args)             {
            string sourcefilePath = 
@"C:\SourceCode\EMPLOYEE\TEST\INPUT\EMP01.xls";                       

string destinationFilePath = 
@"C:\SourceCode\EMPLOYEE\TEST\OUTPUT\EMPFINAL.csv";                   


try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(sourcefilePath))
                {
                    return;
                }


if (File.Exists(errorFile))
                {
                    File.Delete(errorFile);
                }


writeLog("Converting xls to csv....");
                convertExcelToCSV(sourcefilePath, "Sheet1", destinationFilePath);
                writeLog("Parsing data ...");
                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(destinationFilePath);
                string[] info;
                var list = new List<string>();

int rowNum = 1; 

foreach (var line in lines)
                {
                    if (!line.StartsWith("\"")) { continue; }               
                    else if (line.Contains("ID #")) { continue; }           
                    else if (line.Contains("Print Date:")) { continue; }    


else
                    {
                        info = line.Split(',');                                                     
                        if (info.Length < 3) { continue; }                                          
                        if ((info[0] == "\"\"") && (info[1] == "\"\"") && (info[2] == "\"\""))      
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else
                        {

if ((info[1] == "\"\"") && (info[2] == "\"\"") && (info[3] == "\"\"") && (info[4] == "\"\""))                       
                            {
                                var info2 = line.Split(new string[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);                                      
                                var data = rowNum++ + "," + info2[0] + "\",\"" + info2[5] + "\",\"" + info2[9].Replace("\"", "") + "\",\"" + info2[12] + "\""; 
                                list.Add(data);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

File.WriteAllLines(destinationFilePath, list.ToArray()); 
                writeLog("Completed");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                writeLog(ex.ToString()); 
            }           }


private static void writeLog(string message)            {
            File.AppendAllText(errorFile, DateTime.Now.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + message + Environment.NewLine);           }



static void convertExcelToCSV(string sourceFile, string
worksheetName, string targetFile)

{
            string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1\"";
            OleDbConnection conn = null;
            StreamWriter wrtr = null;
            OleDbCommand cmd = null;
            OleDbDataAdapter da = null;

try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                conn.Open();

cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + worksheetName + "$]", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                wrtr = new StreamWriter(targetFile);

da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
                {
                    string rowString = "";
                    for (int y = 0; y < dt.Columns.Count; y++)
                    {
                        rowString += "\"" + dt.Rows[x][y].ToString() + "\",";
                    }
                    wrtr.WriteLine(rowString);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)

{
                writeLog(exc.ToString()); 
            }

finally

{ 
                if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                da.Dispose();
                wrtr.Close();
                wrtr.Dispose();
            }           }

}   }
```

Comment: Consider editing and fxing your code in the question so it is easier to look at.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. This is my first ever post, not sure what I'm doing. Anyway, I just edited the format, hopefully it's better.

Comment: I found the solution.

Comment: Thats great! Post it